# Is there a single word for something that is simultaneously not interesting and not boring?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that would describe a concept or activity, such as playing a game X, that is<sup>1</sup> neither boring nor interesting. In other words, it should mean ‘neutral’ wrt intrestingness (~ boringness) but still comparable on the scale of intrestingness to both ‘boring’ and ‘interesting’.

An example sentence would be

*As far as I'm concerned, long-distance running is* [insert word]; *it is not boring but it's also not interesting.*

Criteria<sup>2</sup>

1. Has to be unambiguous<sup>3</sup>, and may consist of two words at most.
2. Has to be a single word.
3. Should be formal in the sense that it is included in Cambridge Dictionary, or Merriam Webster, or both.
4. Should not contain negating prefixes, such as ‘un-’.

**Does such a word exist in the English language?**

For readers' convenience, please state which criteria you believe your word suggestion has met. You may do so, *e.g.*, by adding a disclaimer at the top or bottom of your answer. Simply writing (1., 2.) is sufficient.

---

> <sup>1</sup> Assume a ternary system of intrestingness.
>
>  <sup>2</sup> If not all criteria can be met, you may relax
>  the requirements from bottom to top, in the following order: 4. -> 3.
>  -> 2. -> 1. Answers with the smallest number of relaxed criteria *in this order* will be preferred in accepting. For example, fulfilling
>  (1., 2., 3.) is better than achieving (1., 3., 4.). Situations where a
>  higher priority ordering fulfills fewer criteria than a lower priority
>  vector, such as (1.) vs (3.,  4.), will be assessed on a case-by-case
>  basis.
>
>  <sup>3</sup> Words such as ‘unappealing’ thus even fail
>  criterium 1 because in a three-valued system ‘unappealing’ ~ ‘not
>  appealing’ ~ ‘not interesting’ can be taken to mean either ‘boring’ or
>  ‘neutral wrt intrestingness’.

Comment: Criteria 4 seems rather arbitrary

Comment: @Orangesandlemons I appreciate your feedback. It is there mostly as a precaution as per footnote 3. To be unambiguous in our three-valued system, the prefix ‘un-’ must negate a word or term that means ‘interesting or boring’. It seemed quite unlikely that such a word existed. But I could be wrong, or the prefix ‘un-’ could also be used in front of a word it is not negating.

Comment: Points 1 and 2 directly contradict each other. Can it be two words or does it have to be a single word? You can't claim both at the same time. If you're merely asking for "hundreds" of submissions, each tagged with the criteria they meet, then this question is off topic. And why are you hiding text in spoiler code?

Comment: @JasonBassford I'm not sure what you mean by direct contradiction. Point 1 says "may consist of two words at most", and point two says "must consist of exactly one word". The latter is a subset of the former; their intersection is "exactly one word". The points 1 and 2 is not equivalent to just requiring a single word because I allowed for not meeting criteria in the order from bottom to top according to footnote 2. (1/2)

Comment: The use of spoiler code here was purely cosmetic. I didn't wish for the question to *seem* too long to the eye; on the other hand, the footnotes clarify and make the question more specific. If this is not allowed, I'm happy to remove this kind of formatting. As for "asking for hundreds of submissions", which part of my question gave this impression? I am also willing to remove or edit any such section. Thanks. (2/2)

Comment: Perhaps the term *middle-of-the-road*!  "If you describe something or someone as middle-of-the-road, you mean that they are ordinary or unexciting". (https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/middle-of-the-road)

Comment: @mahmudkoya Haha. Are hyphenated compound words considered to be a single word in English? I think they are in my native language but not sure about English. If it is considered to be a single word, by my criteria this is a strong candidate for an answer even though I didn't have hyphenated compound words in mind when writing the question. (+1)

Comment: @LinearChristmas, since you are calling it a *compound word*, I don't see any problem in accepting it as a single word. Dictionaries term it as an adjective and also give its noun forms *middle-of-the-roader* and *middle-of-the-roadism*! A synonymous single word is *moderate*.

Comment: By "formal" do you actually mean "widely used"? Both those dictionaries have plenty of words that can only be described as informal, yet are included because they are used frequently enough.

Comment: In Germany they say 'it's 0815' for just ok. What about simply 'ok'?

Answer (score 4):

Bland *may*  be what you are looking for, although it is generally used with the connotation of being boring 
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bland

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had thought of ‘bland’ myself but it does indeed usually mean ‘uninteresting’ which would, in my hypothetical case, imply either boring or neutral wrt intrestingness.

Answer (score 2):

***meh***  According to Merriam Webster, **meh** is:

> —used to express indifference or mild disappointment
>
> First Known Use of meh: 1992
>
> adjective
>
> 1 : not impressive : so-so ·a meh documentary
>
> 2 : apathetic, indifferent ·the movie left me feeling meh

The [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/35993760?redirectedFrom=meh#eid) also lists **meh**, with definition very similar to that of M-W.  However, the OED suggest an earliest use of "1928 or earlier."  **Meh** has made it into the NY Times, as quoted by the OED:

> 2012   N.Y. Times (National ed.) 1 Nov. b13/1   Who else could they
>   root for? The Chicago Bulls? Impossible. The Boston Celtics?
>   Unconscionable. The team in New Jersey? Meh

and into other mainstream publications

> 2010   Time Out N.Y. 20 May 52/1   While this seems like an also-ran
>   collection..even meh Picasso is better than a lot of the stuff out
>   there.

The word is often uttered with a shrug of the shoulders and a deprecating expression on the face.  I always assumed that the origin of **meh** was Yiddish, and was surprised to find, in [meh, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meh#Origin) that its origin is speculative:

> The origin is unknown. Some have speculated that the term's origin is
>   Yiddish because of its similarity to the interjection "feh",[3] which
>   appears in the 1936 Yiddish song Yidl Mitn Fidl. In Alexander
>   Harkavy's "Yiddish-English-Hebrew Dictionary" the word is treated as a
>   bleating or baa sound. Hooray for Yiddish, by Leo Rosten uses the word
>   "mnyeh", which is speculated to be an early variant of "meh".

Comment: This would have been the answer I'd have given, but OP said they were looking for a "formal" word.

Comment: What's not formal with meh?  :)

Comment: It seems to be 'formal enough' for Merriam Websters.  A bit meh, but I'm upvoting.

Comment: This isn't a word that most people would know, only young people into internet slang.

Answer (score 1):

What about [tolerable](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/tolerable?s=t) especially in the second meaning below or its synonyms *endurable* or *bearable*?

**tolerable**

adjective

```
1.capable of being tolerated; endurable: His arrogance is no longer tolerable.
2.fairly good; not bad.
```

*Long distance running is tolerable.*

Another possibility is **mediocre**

```
1. of only ordinary or moderate quality; neither good nor bad;
barely adequate: The car gets only mediocre mileage, but it's fun to drive.
```

*The game was neither boring nor interesting; it was mediocre.*

Answer (score 1):

I suggest 'prosaic'.

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prosaic) defines it as:

> Everyday, ordinary

It's not interesting - it's just the normal run-of-the-mill ordinary.

This answers, I think, all your criteria - 1, 2, 3 and 4.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for ***[unremarkable](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/unremarkable)***:

> **unremarkable**
>   *adjective*
>
> Not particularly interesting or surprising.
>
> *his early childhood was unremarkable*
>   *an unremarkable house*
>
> Pronunciation: *unremarkable* **/ʌnrɪˈmɑːkəb(ə)l/**

It doesn't carry the connotation of **boring** and is by definition **not interesting**.

If it HAS to not use the ***un-*** prefix, then I'd go for ***[common](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/common)***:

> **common**
>   *adjective*
>
> **1.3** Ordinary; of ordinary qualities; without special rank or position.
>   *the dwellings of common people*
>   *a common soldier*
>
> Pronunciation: *common* **/ˈkɒmən/**

Maybe even ***[basic](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/basic)***:

> **basic**
>   *adjective*
>
> **1.1** Offering or constituting the minimum required without elaboration or luxury.
>   *the food was good, if a bit basic*
>
> Pronunciation: *Basic* **/ˈbeɪsɪk/**